# Tabs dentro de modal retornando dados

Tags: php, html5, bootstrap-3

Estou criando uma página que exibe os dados que foram cadastrados e dentro destes dados tenho a opção de Visualizar, Editar, Encerrar e Excluir o registro.

No caso, a opção de Visualizar, Editar e encerrar são acionadas pelo mesmo botão, onde o usuário irá alterar a opção por uma Tab dentro do modal, porém só a primeira Tab que é a de informação funciona, as demais só funcionam no primeiro registro mas não funcionam para os demais, ficando travada.

Vou postar o código abaixo da parte que estou fazendo e gostaria de saber o que poderia ser feito para arrumar este problema.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
     <?PHP
        if(isset($_REQUEST["btnBuscar"])) { 
            $sql_dados = "SELECT  [id],[data],[data_abertura],[designacao],[abordagem],[ponta_a],[localidade_a]
                ,[ponta_b],[localidade_b],[operadora],[contrato],[velocidade],[degrau],[incidente_caixa],[wo_caixa]
                ,[fer_abert],[chamado_operadora],[ambiente],[solucao_problem],[req_sisgt],[data_norm],[status]
                ,[valor],[rota_dur_inc],[usuario_cad],[usuario_alt],[usuario_end],[descricao],[historico]
                 FROM [Ocorrencias].[dbo].[tb_pnl_ocorrencias] WHERE data BETWEEN '$data_ini_' AND '$data_fim_ 23:59:59' ORDER BY data DESC" ;
            } else { 

                $sql_dados = "SELECT  [id],[data],[data_abertura],[designacao],[abordagem],[ponta_a],[localidade_a]
                ,[ponta_b],[localidade_b],[operadora],[contrato],[velocidade],[degrau],[incidente_caixa],[wo_caixa]
                ,[fer_abert],[chamado_operadora],[ambiente],[solucao_problem],[req_sisgt],[data_norm],[status]
                ,[valor],[rota_dur_inc],[usuario_cad],[usuario_alt],[usuario_end],[descricao],[historico]
                 FROM [Ocorrencias].[dbo].[tb_pnl_ocorrencias] WHERE data BETWEEN '$dataAt' AND '$dataAt 23:59:59' ORDER BY data DESC" ;

            } //echo $sql_dados;
    ?>
    <!--Fim do segundo bloco PHP--> 

    <!--Bloco que irá gerar o Excel e irá filtrar o resultado-->
    <form accept-charset="windows-1252" method="POST" action="../UTILS/ocor_xls.php"><!--Aqui irá fazer a ação para gerar o XLS-->

        <input type='hidden' name='datai' value='<?=$data_ini?>'/> 
        <input type='hidden' name='dataf' value='<?=$data_fim?>'/> 

        <!--Campo para escolher a quantidade 
        de registros a exibir na pÃ¡gina-->
        <?=$data_texto;?>
        <p style="font-size:15px; margin-left:15px;">   
        <button  type="submit" style="Border:none; background-image:url('../IMG/excel.jpg'); width: 22px; height: 22px;" title="Gerar Excel" value="Gerar Excel">
        </button>       
        <!--Exibir <select name="formExibir" class="bempequeno">
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
        </select> Registros-->

        <label style="margin-left: 500px;">Filtrar:</label>
        <input type="search" class="mediolargo"  name="caixaPesquisa" placeholder="Filtrar..." id="pesquisa_oco" 
        onkeyup="minhaPesquisa()"/> 
        </p>
        <p style="font-size:15px; margin-left:15px;"> 

        </p>

    </form>     

    <div class="exibirResultados">
        <table id="pnlOcorrencias"> 
            <tr> 

            <th style="width:210px; text-align:center;" onclick="sortTable(0)" class="clickOrder">Designação
                <span class="clickOrderText">Clique no titulo para ordenar em ordem alfabética</span>
            </th>

            <th style="min-width:110px; text-align:center;" onclick="sortTable(1)" class="clickOrder">Operadora
                <span class="clickOrderText">Clique no titulo para ordenar em ordem alfabética</span>
            </th>

            <th style="width:100px; text-align:center;" onclick="sortTable(2)" class="clickOrder">Velocidade
                <span class="clickOrderText">Clique no titulo para ordenar em ordem alfabética</span>
            </th>

            <th style="width:115px; text-align:center;" onclick="sortTable(3)" class="clickOrder">Ponta A
                <span class="clickOrderText">Clique no titulo para ordenar em ordem alfabética</span>
            </th>

            <th style="width:120px; text-align:center;" onclick="sortTable(4)" class="clickOrder">Ponta B
                <span class="clickOrderText">Clique no titulo para ordenar em ordem alfabética</span>
            </th>

            <th style="width:110px; text-align:center;" onclick="sortTable(5)" class="clickOrder">Incidente Caixa
                <span class="clickOrderText">Clique no titulo para ordenar em ordem alfabética</span>
            </th>

            <th style="width:140px; text-align:center;" onclick="sortTable(6)" class="clickOrder">Data Indisponibilidade
                <span class="clickOrderText">Clique no titulo para ordenar em ordem alfabética</span>
            </th>

            <th style="width:140px; text-align:center;" onclick="sortTable(7)" class="clickOrder">Data Normalização
                <span class="clickOrderText">Clique no titulo para ordenar em ordem alfabética</span>
            </th>

            <th style="width:20px; text-align:center;"  class="clickOrder">
                <span class="clickOrderText">Abrir Ocorrência</span>
            </th>

            <th style="width:20px; text-align:center;"  class="clickOrder">
                <span class="clickOrderText">Excluir</span>
            </th>
        </tr> 

        <!--Script para pesquisar na tabela -->
                <script> 
                    //Script usado para refinar a pesquisa da tabela 
                    function minhaPesquisa() { 
                        //declaração de variáveis 
                        var div, input, filter, table, tr,thead, td, i;
                        input = document.getElementById("pesquisa_oco");
                        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                        table = document.getElementById("pnlOcorrencias"); 
                        thead = table.getElementsByTagName("thead");
                        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                        th = table.getElementsByTagName("th");

                        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
                        for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
                            tr[i].style.display = "none";
                                for(var j=0; j<th.length; j++){
                                    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];      
                                    if (td) {
                                        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
                                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                                        break;      
                                        }   
                                    }
                                }
                            } 
                        }       
                </script> 


                <!--Script para ordernar a tabela retirado do W3Schools-->
                <script>
                        function sortTable(n) {
                            var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
                            table = document.getElementById("pnlOcorrencias");
                            switching = true;

                            //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
                            dir = "asc"; 

                            /*Make a loop that will continue until
                            no switching has been done:*/

                            while (switching) {
                            //start by saying: no switching is done:
                            switching = false;
                            rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
                            /*Loop through all table rows (except the
                            first, which contains table headers):*/
                            for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
                            //start by saying there should be no switching:
                            shouldSwitch = false;
                            /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
                            one from current row and one from the next:*/
                            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
                            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
                            /*check if the two rows should switch place,
                            based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
                            if (dir == "asc") {
                                if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                                //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                                shouldSwitch= true;
                                break;
                            }
                            } else if (dir == "desc") {
                                if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                                //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                                shouldSwitch= true;
                                break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (shouldSwitch) {
                            /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
                            and mark that a switch has been done:*/
                            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                            switching = true;
                            //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
                            switchcount ++;      
                        } else {
                            /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
                        set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
                        if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                            dir = "desc";
                            switching = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                </script>

                <!--Terceiro bloco de PHP, executa a consulta-->
                <?

                    //echo $sql_dados;
                    $rsql_ver = $sql->execute($sql_dados); //Executa a Query

                        while (!$rsql_ver->EOF){ //Tratamento dos registros retornados na Query 

                                $id = $rsql_ver->Fields['id']->Value;
                                $data = $rsql_ver->Fields['data']->Value;
                                $data_abertura = $rsql_ver->Fields['data_abertura']->Value;
                                $designacao = $rsql_ver->Fields['designacao']->Value;
                                $abordagem = $rsql_ver->Fields['abordagem']->Value; 
                                $ponta_a = $rsql_ver->Fields['ponta_a']->Value; 
                                $localidade_a = $rsql_ver->Fields['localidade_a']->Value; 
                                $ponta_b = $rsql_ver->Fields['ponta_b']->Value; 
                                $localidade_b = $rsql_ver->Fields['localidade_b']->Value; 
                                $operadora = $rsql_ver->Fields['operadora']->Value;
                                $contrato = $rsql_ver->Fields['contrato']->Value; 
                                $velocidade = $rsql_ver->Fields['velocidade']->Value;
                                $degrau = $rsql_ver->Fields['degrau']->Value; 
                                $incidente_caixa = $rsql_ver->Fields['incidente_caixa']->Value; 
                                $wo_caixa = $rsql_ver->Fields['wo_caixa']->Value; 
                                $fer_abert = $rsql_ver->Fields['fer_abert']->Value; 
                                $chamado_operadora = $rsql_ver->Fields['chamado_operadora']->Value; 
                                $ambiente = $rsql_ver->Fields['ambiente']->Value; 
                                $solucao_problem = $rsql_ver->Fields['solucao_problem']->Value; 
                                $req_sisgt = $rsql_ver->Fields['req_sisgt']->Value; 
                                $data_norm = $rsql_ver->Fields['data_norm']->Value;
                                $status = $rsql_ver->Fields['status']->Value; 
                                $descricao = $rsql_ver->Fields['descricao']->Value;
                                $historico = $rsql_ver->Fields['historico']->Value;
                                $valor = $rsql_ver->Fields['valor']->Value; 
                                $rota_dur_inc = $rsql_ver->Fields['rota_dur_inc']->Value; 
                                $usuario_cad = $rsql_ver->Fields['usuario_cad']->value; 
                                $usuario_alt = $rsql_ver->Fields['usuario_alt']->Value; 
                                $usuario_end = $rsql_ver->Fields['usuario_end']->Value;     

                                echo "
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>$designacao</td>
                                        <td>$operadora</td>
                                        <td>$velocidade</td>
                                        <td>$ponta_a</td>
                                        <td>$ponta_b</td>
                                        <td>$incidente_caixa</td>
                                        <td>$data</td>
                                        <td>$data_norm</td>

                                        <!--Botões--> 
                                            <td style='white-space: nowrap; width:20px;' class='nosort'>
                                                <button type='button' title='Informação' class='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal$id' id='btninfo'><img src='../IMG/info.png' width='20px' height='20px'/></button>
                                            </td>

                                            <td style='white-space: nowrap; width:20px;' class='nosort'> 
                                                <button type='button' title='Excluir' class='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalExcluir$id'><img src='../IMG/erase.png' width='20px' height='20px'/></button>
                                            </td>
                                    </tr>
                                ";

                ?> 
                <!--Fim do Terceiro bloco de PHP--> 

                <!--Estilo que será usado no modal-->
                <style> 

                    /* Style the tab */
                    div.tab { 
                        overflow: hidden;
                        border: 1px solid #ccc;
                        background-color: #f1f1f1;      
                    }       

                    .tablinks { 
                        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
                        font-size: 16px;
                        color: #2e6ebd; 
                        background-color: #eaf4fd;
                        width: 155px;
                        height: 40px;
                        border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
                    }

                    .tablinks:hover { 
                        color: #e1703a;
                    }



                    /* Style the tab content */
                    .tabcontent {
                        display: none;
                        padding: 6px 12px;
                        border: 1px solid #ccc;
                        border-top: none;
                        background-color: #FFFFFF;
                    }   

                    .lista-exibe { 
                        list-style: none; 
                        background-color: #FFFFFF;

                    } 

                    .lista-historico { 
                        list-style: none; 

                    } 

                    .lista-historico li:nth-child(odd) { 
                        background-color: #ccc;     
                    }

                    .lista-historico li:nth-child(even) { 
                        background-color: #fff;
                    }

                </style>


                <!--Início do Modal em TAB--> 

                <div id="myModal<?=$id;?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> 

                    <!--Conteúdo do modal--> 
                    <div class="modal-content" style="width:1000px; background-color: #d5e6f2;"> 

                        <!--Cabeçalho do modal--> 
                        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #d5e6f2; padding: 2px 16px; color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px;">
                            <p style="font-size: 20px; text-align:center; background-color: #b3cce5; color: #0028a5">Ocorrência de nº <b><?=$id;?></b></p>
                        </div> 
                        <!--Fim do Cabeçalho-->

                        <!--Corpo do modal--> 
                        <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #d5e6f2;">

                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabContent" >  
                                <li class="active" style="font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #2e6ebd; background-color: #eaf4fd;  ">
                                    <a href="#registro" data-toggle="tab">Registro de Usuarios</a>
                                </li>

                                <li style="font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #2e6ebd; background-color: #eaf4fd; ">
                                    <a href="#altOco" data-toggle="tab">Alterar Ocorrências</a>
                                </li>
                                <li style="font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #2e6ebd; background-color: #eaf4fd; ">
                                    <a href="#encOco" data-toggle="tab">Encerrar Ocorrências</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            <div class="tab-content">

                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="registro">
                                    <div id="iniciaisInfo">
                                        <p style="font-size: 20px; background-color: #e1edf6;"><b>Dados da Ocorrência:</b></p>
                                            <ul class="lista-exibe">
                                                <li><b>Designação:</b>&nbsp;<?=$designacao;?></li>
                                                <li><b>Ambiente:</b>&nbsp;<?=$ambiente;?></li>          
                                                <li><b>Operadora:</b>&nbsp;<?=$operadora;?></li>
                                                <li><b>Velocidade:</b>&nbsp;<?=$velocidade;?></li>
                                                <li><b>Degrau:</b>&nbsp;<?=$degrau;?></li>
                                                <li><b>Contrato:</b>&nbsp;<?=$contrato;?></li>
                                                <li><b>Abordagem:</b>&nbsp;<?=$abordagem;?></li>
                                                <li><b>Rota durante incidente:</b>&nbsp;<?=$rota_dur_inc;?></li>
                                                <li><b>Equipamento A:</b>&nbsp;<?=$ponta_a;?></li>
                                                <li><b>Localidade A:</b>&nbsp;<?=$localidade_a;?></li> 
                                                <li><b>Equipamento B:</b>&nbsp;<?=$ponta_b;?></li>
                                                <li><b>Localidade B:</b>&nbsp;<?=$localidade_b;?></li> 
                                                <li><b>Incidente Caixa:</b>&nbsp;<?=$incidente_caixa;?></li>
                                                <li><b>WO Caixa:</b>&nbsp;<?=$wo_caixa;?></li>
                                                <li><b>Ferramenta de abertura:</b>&nbsp;<?=$fer_abert;?></li>
                                                <li><b>Chamado operadora:</b>&nbsp;<?=$chamado_operadora;?></li>
                                                <li><b>Data/hora de indisponibilidade:</b>&nbsp;<?=$data;?></li>
                                                <li><b>Data/hora abertura:</b>&nbsp;<?=$data_abertura;?></li>   
                                                <li><b>Data/Hora normalização:</b>&nbsp;<?=$data_norm;?></li>
                                                <li><b>Requisição SISGT:</b>&nbsp;<?=$req_sisgt;?></li> 
                                                <li><b>Status:</b>&nbsp;<?=$status;?></li>
                                            </ul>

                                        <p style="font-size: 20px; background-color: #e1edf6;"><b>Registro de usuários:</b></p>         
                                            <ul class="lista-historico"> 
                                                <li><?=$historico;?></li>
                                            </ul>       


                                        <p style="font-size: 20px; background-color: #e1edf6;"><b>Solução do problema:</b></p> 
                                            <ul class="lista-exibe"> 
                                                <li><?=$solucao_problem;?></li>
                                            </ul>           
                                    </div>          

                                </div>      

                                <div class="tab-pane " id="altOco">
                                    <iframe src="AlterarOcorrencias.php?id=<?echo $id;?>" style="width: 950px; height: 600px;  "></iframe>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tab-pane " id="encOco">
                                    <iframe src="EncerraOcorrencia.php?id=<?echo $id;?>" style="width: 950px; height: 300px;  "></iframe>
                                </div>

                            </div>              

                        </div>
                        <!--Fim do Corpo do modal-->


                        <!--Rodapé do modal-->
                        <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: #d5e6f2; padding: 2px 16px; color: #FFFFFF"> 
                            <h4 style="text-align: left">CGR-CETEC27</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="botaoG" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar Janela</button>
                        </div> 
                        <!--Fim do rodapé-->
                    </div> 
                </div>



                <!--Quanrto bloco em PHP --Final do tratamento de registros--> 
                <?              
                //$cont++;


                    $rsql_ver->MoveNext();          
                }   

                ?>
```